# What does NKX2-5 do?

Tags: cardiology, genetics, development-disorder

Where is the gene '*NKX2-5*' located and what is its function? How is it relevant to developmental disorders?

Comment: I'm no expert and I'm sure you have explored the net, but I wonder whether you have found this site https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/NKX2-5

Comment: @Mikel, thank you for that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mammalian cells the gene NKX2-5 is found on chromosome 5, more specifically on the long (q) arm of chromosome 5 at position 35.1. (Cytogenetic Location: 5q35.1)

NKX2-5 is ~3,213 nucleotide bases long and is involved in biological processes that give an organism its shape. Disruption of NKX2-5 has proven to cause abnormal heart shape.

More information can be found: [here](https://geneticsperspective.blogspot.com/2020/04/nkx2-5-gene-overview.html)